# Positive definiteness of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is positive definite of order $k$. Let $X$ be of order $k \times n$. Is $W := X'AX$ necessarily positive definite?

Maybe it is something like a theorem of Sylvester, but I have been unable to find a theorem.

Thanks

Comment: If $X$ is the zero matrix, $W$ will certainly not be positive definite. There are other almost-but-not-quite-as-trivial examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W$ will be positive semidefinite, with (strict) positive definiteness achieved if and only if $X$ is of a full column rank. This is easy to see.

By definition, $w^T A w \ge 0$ for all $w$, with $w^T A w = 0$ if and only if $w = 0$. So, for any $v$ we can define $w := Xv$ and get:

$$v^T (X^T A X) v = (Xv)^T A (Xv) = w^T A w \ge 0.$$

As I've said before, we get zero if and only if $w = 0$, i.e., if and only if $Xv = 0$. Note that

$$Xv = 0 \iff v = 0$$

if and only if $X$ is of a full column rank. In other words, $v^T W v = 0$ only for $v = 0$ (i.e., $W$ is strictly positive definite) if and only if $X$ is of a full column rank.

A "theorem of Sylvester" you mention is probably [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), which is closely related, but not exactly what you ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: Sylvester's theorem is a common term in some countries, and its statement is: Let $\Delta_i$ be the leading minors. Then $A$ is PD iff $\Delta_i>0 \ \forall i$ and is ND iff $(-1)^i\Delta_i>0\ \forall i$.

Comment: @tohecz Thank you. I know it as a [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Comment: @VedranŠego I would say that this is a minor nuance in terminology. Anyways, it certainly doesn't really help here since it's easier to prove the correct statement from definition than using Sylvester.